# Extracting text based on condition in R

Tags: r, regex, text, data-manipulation, text-extraction

I am relatively new to R. I have a character variable named `RN` whose text needs to be extracted into 2 variables [`named_RN` and `general_RN`] based on some conditions on `RN`. This is what the desired result is (right now, `named_RN` and `general_RN` are blank - I don't know how to code this part and that's what I need help on!):

```
RN                                              named_RN         general_RN
RP4A60D26L (Pentazocine)                        Pentazocine
0 (Complement C4)                                                Complement C4
0 (Aminocap) U6206 (Amino)                      Amino            Aminocap
N3R30 (Amiodarone) 0 (Benzo) 0 (Ferri)          Amiodarone       Benzo, Ferri
```

As you can see, I am trying to extract the information within the parentheses. However, I want to extract from `RN` into `general_RN` if it has a code of `0` and extract into `named_RN` if it has a non-zero code.

The main problem I am running into is that I cannot gsub by `0 (` or `0 (` [space before 0 in the latter one because sometimes the `0` code starts in the middle of the text in `RN` as is the case in the last row] because some of the codes for `named_RN` end with `0 (` as is the case in the last row.

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: So RN contains a list of pairs, where the first element of pair is either "0" or something else, and the second element of the pair is the parenthetical item?

Comment: sure, that's one way to look at it. it's not in list format though. it's merely character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Basically, I create a new column where matches are easier to detect. Then, I match the inside of the parenthesis with `regmatches`.

```
df <- read.table(text="RN
'RP4A60D26L (Pentazocine)'
'0 (Complement C4)'
'0 (Aminocap) U6206 (Amino)'
'N3R30 (Amiodarone) 0 (Benzo) 0 (Ferri)'",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$RN_temp <- gsub("^[0] "," general_RN",df$RN) #replace leading 0s w/ general_RN
df$RN_temp <- gsub(" [0] "," general_RN",df$RN_temp) #replace other " 0 "
df$RN_temp <- gsub(" \\("," named_RN(",df$RN_temp) #replace rest w/ named_RN
df$RN_temp

df$named_RN <- regmatches(df$RN_temp,gregexpr("(?<=named_RN\\().*?(?=\\))",
                df$RN_temp, perl=TRUE))
df$general_RN <- regmatches(df$RN_temp,gregexpr("(?<=general_RN\\().*?(?=\\))", 
                  df$RN_temp, perl=TRUE))
df$RN_temp <- NULL
df
```

**EDIT**
To transform into a `data.frame`. I use `lapply(df$named_RN, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x))` to change missing values (NULL) to NA.

```
df$named_RN <- unlist(lapply(df$named_RN, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x)))
df$general_RN <- unlist(df$general_RN)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ RN        : chr  "RP4A60D26L (Pentazocine)" "0 (Complement C4)" "0 (Aminocap) U6206 (Amino)" "N3R30 (Amiodarone) 0 (Benzo) 0 (Ferri)"
 $ named_RN  : chr  "Pentazocine" NA "Amino" "Amiodarone"
 $ general_RN: chr  "Complement C4" "Aminocap" "Benzo" "Ferri"
                                      RN    named_RN    general_RN
1               RP4A60D26L (Pentazocine) Pentazocine              
2                      0 (Complement C4)             Complement C4
3             0 (Aminocap) U6206 (Amino)       Amino      Aminocap
4 N3R30 (Amiodarone) 0 (Benzo) 0 (Ferri)  Amiodarone  Benzo, Ferri
```

Comment: woah, yeah this worked! I really like your algorithm too. I need to look more into regmatches/gregexpr and thoroughly learn those functions. all the (?/.*< etc symbols overwhelm me, ah. from where do you recommend learning them?

Comment: I'm not a regex expert, but I learned the basics on this site: https://regexone.com/

Comment: I do have one (very basic) question. your code results in my dataframe being listed like `c("Benzo", "Ferri")` or `character(0)` if it's empty. how can I change it to simple `Benzo, Ferri` and an empty string instead? not sure why I am not able to unlist...I'll play around a bit more though.

Comment: I'm not able to, for instance `df$general_RN <- unlist(df$general_RN)` because `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, general_RN, value = c("Drug Combinations",  : 
  replacement has 1992 rows, data has 10479`

Comment: hm, for `named_RN` it only kept the first element of each list when I want all retained. for `general_RN` I received the following error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, general_RN, value = c("Drug Combinations",  : 
  replacement has 1992 rows, data has 10479`

Comment: hi, I have a follow up - I just noticed that some of the `RN` look like `EC 1.6.2.2 (Cytochrome-B(5) Reductase)` and while it correctly does extract it into the `named_RN` variable, it fails to correctly extract the entire phrase - only `Cytochrome-B(5` is retained, instead of `Cytochrome-B(5) Reductase`. is there a way to only remove the last parenthesis? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Wile I did use `gsub`,  I also used `string_match_all` from the `stringr`
package. To get around the problem you mentioned (that codes may contain 0), you can just use the `\\b` assertion to restrict that the 0 is not part of a longer string.

First named_RN

```
library(stringr)

## named_RN 
namedTemp = gsub("\\b0\\s+\\((.*?)\\)\\s*", "", RN)
namedTemp = sapply(str_extract_all(namedTemp, "\\([^\\)]+\\)"), 
            paste, collapse=", ")
(named_RN  = gsub("[()]", "", namedTemp))
[1] "Pentazocine" ""            "Amino"       "Amiodarone"
```

then general_RN

```
## general_RN 
generalTemp = sapply(str_extract_all(RN, "\\b0\\s+\\((.*?)\\)"), 
    paste, collapse=", ")
generalTemp = gsub("\\b0\\s+", "", generalTemp)
(general_RN = gsub("[()]", "", generalTemp))
[1] ""              "Complement C4" "Aminocap"      "Benzo, Ferri"
```

Comment: oh this almost worked! except that some of the `named_RN` codes look something like 9002-68-0 in which case your code labelled it as `general_RN` instead of `named_RN.`